# RVM: how can I dynamically export gem executable directory in my path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I installed rvm as root to setup an Ubuntu LTS 8.04 as a web hosting server for my rails apps.

rvm is installed in:

```
/usr/local/rvm
```

Everything works fine, gems installation included and users are able to use ruby and gem commands.

```
sudo gem install rails
```

My problem is that the gems EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY is not included in my PATH and thus I cannot use rails command.

Is there a way to dynamycally include gems executable directory in my PATH?

Can it be done directly through rvm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't have RVM setup correctly if it's not in your path.

First, If you run:

```
type rvm | head -1
```

and it returns anything other "rvm is a function" then you are not loading it correctly in your profiles.

Second, you may want to include global definitions for the users profiles.

In your users' .bashrc or equivalent

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

And then in your `/etc/bashrc`, add your executable path.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your PATH was overwritten somewhere on the way, you can put that on end of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$(echo $GEM_PATH | sed 's/:/\/bin:/g')/bin:$MY_RUBY_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

it is not pretty but should work